# Leavers Script to disable users in AD, Remove Groups, delete profile and move home folders

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

i am pretty new to powershell and im not great at coding, but i have managed to cobble together code from around the net to help save time when removing old students accounts in AD.

Code currently does the following;

- Takes leavers from .csv file moves the leavers to leavers OU,
- Disables Account, and removes from all groups Moves their home folder
  to the Leavers Archive share
- Deletes their profiles .v5 and .v6 folders

What I'm hoping is that someone more experienced can take a look at the code
and possibly explain how it could be tidied and cleaned up and condensed if possible, We have 4 different shares split A-D,E-J,K-R,S-Z

In order to do what i needed for each share i just duplicated the code for each share. I am sure that this could be better formatted with while loops, and IF statements but i don't fully understand how they work to be honest.

Here's the code.

```
    #################################################################################

#Disables Student accounts for leavers and moves them to the leavers OU
#Disables Parent Accounts, Strips groups, Moves to Parent Leavers OU

    #################################################################################

    #Import users to be disabled

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    #Create working directory
    #New-Item -ItemType directory "C:\LeaversExports"

    Import-Csv "C:\Leavers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
    Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Disable-ADAccount
    Write-host -ForegroundColor Green "$samAccountName Disabled"
    }

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################
    #Move users from SD1 to Leavers SD1
    $SD1 = "OU=SD1,OU=Students,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    $SD1Leavers = "OU=Leavers SD1,OU=Students,OU=Leavers,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase $SD1 -properties name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,homedirectory,ProfilePath |select SamAccountName,homedirectory,ProfilePath | export-csv C:\LeaversExports\SD1_Leavers.csv -nti
    Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled –UsersOnly –SearchBase $SD1 | Move-ADObject –TargetPath $SD1Leavers
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD1 - Disabled users Moved"


    # Remove User from All Group Memberships
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD1Leavers -Filter *
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$False


    $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD1Leavers -Filter * 

    foreach($user in $users){
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SamAccountName | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike '*Domain*'}
      foreach($group in $groups){

        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -erroraction silentlycontinue

      }
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD1 Leavers removed from all Groups"

    #Move SD1 Leavers Home Area to Archive
    $CSVPath      = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD1_Leavers.csv'
    $NewHomeRoot  = '\\FS1\A-D Leavers$\Leavers 18-19$'
    #$NewHomeLocal = 'D:\Data\Users'

    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        $NewHome   = Join-Path -Path $NewHomeRoot -ChildPath $User.SamAccountName

        Robocopy.exe $User.homedirectory $NewHome /MIR /MOVE

        }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All SD1 Leavers Home Folders Moved to Archive"

    #Delete Profile Folders
    $CSVPath = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD1_Leavers.csv'
    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath
    $samAccountName = $Users.SamAccountName
    $profilepathv6 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V6"
    $profilepathv5 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V5"

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv6){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv6)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
        }
        Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv5){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv5 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv5)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv5 - has been deleted"
        }
            Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V5 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
    }

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
    #Clean up working files
    #Remove-Item "C:\LeaversExports" -Force -recurse

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################
    #Move users from SD2 to Leavers SD2
    $SD2 = "OU=SD2,OU=Students,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    $SD2Leavers = "OU=Leavers SD2,OU=Students,OU=Leavers,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase $SD2 -properties name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,homedirectory,ProfilePath |select SamAccountName,homedirectory,ProfilePath | export-csv C:\LeaversExports\SD2_Leavers.csv -nti
    Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled –UsersOnly –SearchBase $SD2 | Move-ADObject –TargetPath $SD2Leavers
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD2 - Disabled users Moved"


    # Remove User from All Group Memberships
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD2Leavers -Filter *
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$False


    $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD2Leavers -Filter * 

    foreach($user in $users){
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SamAccountName | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike '*Domain*'}
      foreach($group in $groups){

        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -erroraction silentlycontinue

      }
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD2 Leavers removed from all Groups"

    #Move SD2 Leavers Home Area to Archive
    $CSVPath      = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD2_Leavers.csv'
    $NewHomeRoot  = '\\FS1\E-J Leavers$\Leavers 18-19'
    #$NewHomeLocal = 'D:\Data\Users'

    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        $NewHome   = Join-Path -Path $NewHomeRoot -ChildPath $User.SamAccountName

        Robocopy.exe $User.homedirectory $NewHome /MIR /MOVE

        }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All SD2 Leavers Home Folders Moved to Archive"

    #Delete Profile Folders
    $CSVPath = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD2_Leavers.csv'
    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath
    $samAccountName = $Users.SamAccountName
    $profilepathv6 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V6"
    $profilepathv5 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V5"

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv6){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv6)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
        }
        Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv5){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv5 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv5)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv5 - has been deleted"
        }
            Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V5 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
    }

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
    #Clean up working files
    #Remove-Item "C:\LeaversExports" -Force -recurse

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################
    #Move users from SD3 to Leavers SD3
    $SD3 = "OU=SD3,OU=Students,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    $SD3Leavers = "OU=Leavers SD3,OU=Students,OU=Leavers,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase $SD3 -properties name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,homedirectory,ProfilePath |select SamAccountName,homedirectory,ProfilePath | export-csv C:\LeaversExports\SD3_Leavers.csv -nti
    Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled –UsersOnly –SearchBase $SD3 | Move-ADObject –TargetPath $SD3Leavers
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD3 - Disabled users Moved"


    # Remove User from All Group Memberships
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD3Leavers -Filter *
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$False


    $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD3Leavers -Filter * 

    foreach($user in $users){
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SamAccountName | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike '*Domain*'}
      foreach($group in $groups){

        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -erroraction silentlycontinue

      }
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD3 Leavers removed from all Groups"

    #Move SD3 Leavers Home Area to Archive
    $CSVPath      = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD3_Leavers.csv'
    $NewHomeRoot  = '\\FS2\K-R Leavers$\Leavers 18-19'
    #$NewHomeLocal = 'D:\Data\Users'

    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        $NewHome   = Join-Path -Path $NewHomeRoot -ChildPath $User.SamAccountName

        Robocopy.exe $User.homedirectory $NewHome /MIR /MOVE

        }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All SD3 Leavers Home Folders Moved to Archive"

    #Delete Profile Folders
    $CSVPath = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD3_Leavers.csv'
    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath
    $samAccountName = $Users.SamAccountName
    $profilepathv6 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V6"
    $profilepathv5 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V5"

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv6){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv6)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
        }
        Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv5){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv5 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv5)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv5 - has been deleted"
        }
            Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V5 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
    }

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
    #Clean up working files
    #Remove-Item "C:\LeaversExports" -Force -recurse

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################

    ##############################################################################################################################################################################################
    #Move users from SD4 to Leavers SD4
    $SD4 = "OU=SD4,OU=Students,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    $SD4Leavers = "OU=Leavers SD4,OU=Students,OU=Leavers,DC=Contoso,DC=ac,DC=uk"
    Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase $SD4 -properties name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,homedirectory,ProfilePath |select SamAccountName,homedirectory,ProfilePath | export-csv C:\LeaversExports\SD4_Leavers.csv -nti
    Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled –UsersOnly –SearchBase $SD4 | Move-ADObject –TargetPath $SD4Leavers
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD4 - Disabled users Moved"


    # Remove User from All Group Memberships
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD4Leavers -Filter *
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$False


    $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SD4Leavers -Filter * 

    foreach($user in $users){
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SamAccountName | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike '*Domain*'}
      foreach($group in $groups){

        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -erroraction silentlycontinue

      }
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SD4 Leavers removed from all Groups"

    #Move SD4 Leavers Home Area to Archive
    $CSVPath      = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD4_Leavers.csv'
    $NewHomeRoot  = '\\FS2\S-Z Leavers$\Leavers 18-19'
    #$NewHomeLocal = 'D:\Data\Users'

    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        $NewHome   = Join-Path -Path $NewHomeRoot -ChildPath $User.SamAccountName

        Robocopy.exe $User.homedirectory $NewHome /MIR /MOVE

        }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All SD4 Leavers Home Folders Moved to Archive"

    #Delete Profile Folders
    $CSVPath = 'C:\LeaversExports\SD4_Leavers.csv'
    $Users = Import-Csv $CSVPath
    $samAccountName = $Users.SamAccountName
    $profilepathv6 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V6"
    $profilepathv5 = $Users.ProfilePath + ".V5"

    foreach( $User in $Users ){
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv6){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv6)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
        }
        Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
        if (Test-Path $profilepathv5){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv5 Path Found"
        Remove-Item ($profilepathv5)-Force -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv5 - has been deleted"
        }
            Else{

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V5 Path Not found - Skipped"

        }
    }

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
    #Clean up working files
    #Remove-Item "C:\LeaversExports" -Force -recurse

    #################################################################################
```

Comment: hopefully the name change to the title is better now, sorry was recommended to post here from stackoverflow. Wasn't sure of the best way to post.

Comment: Yes, looks much better.  I hope you get some good suggestions (sorry I can't review - I don't know this language).